# How calculate success (in %) related to amount?

Tags: php, math, calculation

Want know the success (in percentage) of a software update advertising between all my clients.

I have the following formula, but i think that something is wrong (based in preliminary result), see:

```
$success = round((($total_pcs_with_new_version) + (($total_pcs_with_old_version)))/100, 2);

/**

[====== Preliminary result ======]

$total_pcs_with_new_version = 13;
$total_pcs_with_old_version = 23

then result will be:

$success = 0.36%

**/
```

Comment: You want `(thing / total) * 100` to get a percentage in a standard human-readable form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation isn't correct:

```
$success = round($total_pcs_with_new_version * 100 /
                ($total_pcs_with_new_version + $total_pcs_with_old_version), 2);
```

- `new * 100 / total`
- `13  * 100 / 36 = 36.11`